# Django Query Count Records on Row

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm a little rusty with django.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how I count the db objects from this query:

```
UserEnteredTld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user, auth=0)
```

I used to do:

```
UserEnteredTld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user, auth=0).count()
```

In the **template** (with the var):

```
{% if UserEnteredTld  %}    
    <h3>I have Tld's</h3>
{% endif %}
```

**the view:**

```
UserEnteredTld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user, auth=0).count()
UserAuthTld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user,auth=1).count()

return render(request, 'accounthome.html', {
         'UserEnteredTld':UserEnteredTld,
         'UserAuthTld':UserAuthTld
    })
```

**model**

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    FKtoClient = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

but, this appears to not be outputting anything. (I verified actual rows exist...)

To be clear: I'm simply trying to count the number of rows for the `Tld` table where a `ForeignKey` exists for the logged in user and the `auth=0`.

Comment: This is very odd. No errors? No messages? Nothig?

Comment: count is the correct method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#count can you provide more info or how you're outputting the data?

Comment: Sure, I've added the IF statement above. Anything?

Comment: It's possible that `UserEnteredTld` is actually 0? Or more important, are you providing this variable from your view?

Comment: This view is coming from a view to a django template. UserEnteredTld is checking if a row (or more) exists or not

Comment: Yes, I get it. But, the view rendering your template has to provide a variable called `UserEnteredTld` and its value to the template. Can you post the code of your view. This we help us to help you.

Comment: Added it above - let me know what you think

Comment: Can you paste the code of your model?

Comment: @santiagobasulto - please see the model above

Comment: You have to use "False" not "0". Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `count` for that. Use `exists` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)).

```
user_entered_tld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient=request.user, auth=False).exists()

{% if user_entered_tld  %}    
    <h3>I have Tld's</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Some notes:

- Django latest version is 1.7 (on beta). It's impossible you're using 2.6.2 (that seems like a Python version)
- Don't camel-case your variables. Use `user_entered_tld` instead of
  `UserEnteredTld`. It's a good Python convention.

Comment: Great points here.... unfortunately this is doing no different. I've triple checked the [Tld] table and a row does exist for the currently logged in user

Comment: try printing the value and see what's returning.